# Failed to find csproj file in folder - unable to create c# template in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

Following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieYrBWmkfno&ab_channel=ACloudGuru
where I have to create an azure function using c#.

On the video, creating a template it creates all necessary files. But in my case it does not.

Choosing HTTP Trigger template it does not create any files in my folder.
Only creates `local.settings.json` file.

Installed:

SDK 6.0

SDK 3.1

Azure extension (includes Azure functions)

C# extension

What am I missing here?

[image]

Then having this error message:

[image]

Update: Azure function core tools installed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Recently, Visual Studio Code has changed the User Interface for the Azure Extension Resources**.

**Step 1**:

[image]

- When you click on **Create Function** option, it will ask you every step like Select language, Runtime, Type of Trigger, Authorization Level, Function Name, Workspace Path, etc.
- When you click on **Create HTTP Function** option, it will ask you all the above options except Type of Trigger because the option creates only HTTP Trigger which is a shortcut of creating it.

**Step 2**:

Resources required are:

1. Visual Studio Code IDE
2. .NET SDK 3.1, 5, 6 depends on your requirement
3. [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash) (v3 and v4 as v3 is required for .NET 3.1 and 5 and v4 is required for .NET Core 6).
4. VS Code Extensions (Azure Account, Azure Functions, C#)
5. Azure Storage Emulator or Azurite

**Output 1 using Create Function option in a New Folder using VS Code**:

[image: UsingOption1VSCodeAzF]

**Output 2 using Create HTTP Function option in a sub folder of the Frontend Project using VS Code**:

[image: UsingOptionCreateHTTPFunction]

**Output 3 using Command Palette for Creating Azure Functions .NET 6 Project in VS Code**:

[image: usingcmdpalettevscode]

Comment: Thanks. I did follow this way to create a project. However, it does not create any template. Right bottom corner displays error: "Failed to find csproj file in a foder myfolder". Do you know what is going on?

Comment: Have you installed `Azure Functions Core Tools` ?

Comment: Yes, it is installed. I updated question

Comment: Which dotnet core version you created either 3.1 or 6 LTS ?

Comment: ,NET core 3 LTS is popping up in my VS Code. But I believe I also installed 6

Comment: Take the example of .NET Core 3/6 Azure Functions Project > Have you installed both the .NET Core SDK and Runtime of that versions. I said, For .NET Core 6, you have to install Azure Function Core Tools V4 also - did you installed them? https://i.imgur.com/JrLheTc.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245868/discussion-between-harikrishnarajoli-mt-and-serdia).

Comment: @Serdia, please check the updated answer regarding creation of Azure Functions DotNet Project using Command Palette in VS Code!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the permissions on a folder, where I put the project.
It was Network Drive UNC path.
After moving the project to different location `C:\user\myproject` it started to work.